# Creating an interrupt in c for windows operating system

Tags: c, windows, timer, scheduled-tasks, interrupt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
..

int main()
{

while(1)
{
Timer1();   // Timer1 calls the function called TASK1 for every2ms (CreateTimerQueueTimer)
Timer2();   // Timer2 calls the function called TASK2 for every10ms 
Timer3();   // Timer3 calls the function called TASK3 for every100ms 
}
return 0:
}


int Timer1()  // This is only a Timer1 code
{

    int arg;
    HANDLE Task1;
    HANDLE HTimer1 =NULL;
    HANDLE HTimerQueue1 = NULL;
    Task1 = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if(NULL == Task1)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //create a timer queue
    HTimerQueue1 = CreateTimerQueue();
    if(NULL == HTimerQueue1)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    //phNewTimer - Pointer to a handle; this is an out value
    //TimerQueue - Timer queue handle. For the default timer queue, NULL
    //Callback - Pointer to the callback function
    //Parameter - Value passed to the callback function
    //DueTime - Time (milliseconds), before the timer is set to the signaled state for the first time 
    //Period - Timer period (milliseconds). If zero, timer is signaled only once
    //Flags - One or more of the next values (table taken from MSDN):

    //set the timer to call the timer routine in 2ms
    if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &HTimer1, HTimerQueue1, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TASK1, &arg, 0,2,0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }


    //Delete all timers in the timer queue
    if(!DeleteTimerQueue(HTimerQueue1))
        printf("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

I have created a Timer1 function which calls the TASK1 function or every2ms. I am calling the timer1 function from the main function.
My problem : I put the timer1, timer2 and timer3 within the while loop then its calling the TASK functions as expected. If i want to stop this then what is the idea ?? Do i want to create a interrupt for that ??  If i remove the while loop then it's not calling the function for every 2ms, 10ms and so on. How to create a interrupt for the above program ??

Comment: If you remove the while(1) loop then your main() function will exit and your program will terminate before any timer callback can occur.  Arbitrarily replace it with "Hit any key to continue" code.

Comment: if I remove the while loop then it's executing only three times. But I created a timer for every 2ms, 10ms and so on.

Comment: You'll of course need to remove DeleteTimerQueue() to get the timer to make the callback repeatedly.

Comment: why is it not calling for every2ms , 10ms ??

Comment: I removed DeleteTimerQueue() function then also it's not working.

Comment: @user2984410 check simple working example based on yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Remove `DeleteTimerQueueTimer` .and as noted on comment do it outside of `while` loop
And instead of writing three time  function you could write one with parameters.

Here is simple non-completed example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

VOID CALLBACK task1(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    int* arg=(int*)lpParam;
    printf("task1 we are called with arg %d\n",*arg);

}

VOID CALLBACK task2(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
int* arg=(int*)lpParam;
    printf("task2 we are called with arg %d\n",*arg);
}

VOID CALLBACK task3(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
 int* arg=(int*)lpParam;
    printf("task3 we are called with arg %d\n",*arg);
}

HANDLE TimerTask(unsigned int period,WAITORTIMERCALLBACK task,void* arg)  ;
int main()
{
    int arg1=1,arg2=2,arg3=3;

HANDLE h1=TimerTask(2,task1,&arg1)  ;
HANDLE h2=TimerTask(10,task2,&arg2)  ;
HANDLE h3=TimerTask(8,task3,&arg3)  ;

getchar();
return 0;
}

HANDLE TimerTask(unsigned int period,WAITORTIMERCALLBACK task,void* arg)  
{

    HANDLE HTimer =NULL;

    //set the timer to call the timer routine in 2ms
    if(!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &HTimer, NULL, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)task,(PVOID) arg, 0,period*1000,0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }


    return HTimer;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a example for the software interrupts for the above example ?? I know about the theory of interrupt but confused with respect to programming.

Comment: @user2984410 it is better to use kernel functions. Plus most of interrupts for windows undocummented.I never spotted them for windows

Comment: I used your main function and HANDLE Timer Task function. I Modified the call backs as per my requirement. Is it the right way ??

Comment: yes it is. plus you can look at msdn for proper usage and documentation on winapi functions