# I want to slow down for a while just one command and not the program - beginner level - C ++

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

I wanted to create a key counter with seconds. I tried this, but it slows down the program, not just the seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int x = 1;
int secs = 0;
int clicks = 0;


int main() {
    while (true) {
        if (x == 1) {
            secs++;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Clicks: " << clicks << "             Time: " << secs;
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (2 == x) {
            _getch();
            clicks++;
            system("CLS");
            cout << "Clicks: " << clicks << "             Time: " << secs;
            x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a thread

Comment: During the time that the program is *not* printing a message, *what should happen in between* while waiting?

Comment: try chrono library

Comment: Hello, @Raildex .............When any key is pressed it should add 1 to the clicks. Meanwhile, seconds must be active and change every 1000 miliseconds. I tried this, but instead of slow down just the seconds, it slows down the whole program.

Comment: @thanasisk09: Please [edit] the question in order to clarify it. This is important information that should be in the question itself.

Comment: Why don't you simply use [`GetTickCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount) in order to determine how many seconds have passed? You can call it once at the start of the program and remember this value, and then call it again later  and calculate the time difference, in order to determine how many seconds have passed.

Comment: Hello, @BuildSucceeded ..........I'm a started. I know a little about it, but I can't understand you. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Hello, @AndreasWenzel ....I have also a problem about this. I used _getch() to make the clicks wait a user input. Doing this I'm make the whole program wait for the user, instead of the seconds.

Comment: @thanasisk09: You are probably looking for the function [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects). That function will allow you to wait on console input and on a timer, at the same time. The function will return as soon as either occurs. However, I am not sure if that function is compatible with `getch`. You may have to use a lower-level API for keyboard input, such as [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole).

Comment: Thanks, @AndreasWenzel . I found my problem. I want to slow down only a line. I'm starter and I have a question. (This is a basic solution to my problem) Can I do something like that:             `time++; lineSleep(1000);`

Comment: @thanasisk09: On second thought, I believe that [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) would be better than `ReadConsole`, as that function has more similarity to [`getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch?view=msvc-170).

Comment: @thanasisk09: What exactly does `lineSleep` do? Did you write that function yourself?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes. It's just an example to make you understand my thought. My thought is to use a function, like that, but to exist. This function has to slow down just the line, not the _place_ where it is.

Comment: @thanasisk09: Would it be acceptable to you to count the number of keystrokes after one second has elapsed, so that it is acceptable that the program freezes until then? Or do you need the keystrokes to be processed immediately?

Comment: @thanasisk09: If you only want to prevent the function `getch` from blocking, then you can call the function [`kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-170) to determine whether keyboard input is waiting, and only call the function `getch` if `kbit` tells you that keyboard input is waiting.

Comment: you can also use alarm and SIGALARM see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html

Comment: @pm100: Since OP is doing `#include <Windows.h>`, I assume that OP is using Microsoft Windows.

Comment: or since its windows use SetTimer @AndreasWenzel (ty, I missed the include) which does roughly the same thing

Comment: @pm100: According to the documentation of the function [`SetTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer), the calling thread requires a functioning message queue to dispatch the message, even if a timer callback function is used. I strongly doubt that OP has such a message queue. Therefore, it would probably be better to use [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer). However, in my answer, I found it unnecessary to create a separate timer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718762/creating-an-interrupt-in-c-for-windows-operating-system?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955617/win32-read-from-stdin-with-timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want the [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep) function to not block the entire program while waiting for the timer, but to instead continue processing keyboard input while waiting for the timer. Also, you seem to want the [`getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170) function to not block the entire program while waiting for keyboard input, but to instead continue processing timers while waiting for keyboard input. However, this is not the way that these functions work. Both functions will continue blocking forever, until the specific type of event occurs that they are waiting for.

What you instead want is a function that is able to wait on several different types of events simultaneously. The function should block until any one of these events occurs. As soon as such an event occurs, the function should return immediately and specify what type of event occurred, i.e. whether it was a timer event or a keyboard input event. That way, the event can be handled immediately.

Generally, you can use the function [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) for this purpose. However, in this case, the function [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) is sufficient, as that function will allow you to specify a timeout interval in addition to the object handle that you want to wait on. That way, you can wait on both a timer and on an object handle for keyboard input.

Unfortunately, according to my tests, using `WaitForSingleObject` on the input handle of a console will only work reliably when processing console input using low-level Console API functions such as [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput). It seems it cannot reliably predict whether [`kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=msvc-170) and [`getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170) will work, and it also won't work reliably with [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole).

I believe that this program accomplishes what you want:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hStdin = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    ULONGLONG ullStartTime;

    //counter of the number of times a keypress was registered
    int num_keypresses = 0;

    //get input handle
    hStdin= GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
    if ( hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        std::cerr << "error opening input handle!\n" << std::flush;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //remember time that program started
    ullStartTime = GetTickCount64();

    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        ULONGLONG ullElapsedTime = GetTickCount64() - ullStartTime;

        int seconds   = (int) ( ullElapsedTime / 1000 );
        int remainder = (int) ( ullElapsedTime % 1000 );

        //round up to next second, if appropriate
        if ( remainder >= 500 )
        {
            seconds++;
            remainder -= 1000;
        }

        //uncomment the folllowing line to clear the screen
        //std::system( "cls" );

        //write data to screen
        std::cout << "Keypresses: " << num_keypresses << "     Time: " << seconds << " seconds\n" << std::flush;

        //wait for either a keypress to occur, or for a timeout to occur
        switch ( WaitForSingleObject( hStdin, 1000 - remainder ) )
        {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            {
                DWORD dwRead;
                INPUT_RECORD ir;

                //console input event occurred, so read it
                if ( !ReadConsoleInput( hStdin, &ir, 1, &dwRead ) || dwRead != 1 )
                {
                    std::cerr << "error reading input!\n" << std::flush;
                    std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                if ( ir.EventType == KEY_EVENT && ir.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown )
                {
                    num_keypresses += ir.Event.KeyEvent.wRepeatCount;
                }
                break;
            }
            case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            {
                //timeout occurred
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                std::cerr << "unexpected error!\n" << std::flush;
                std::exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I wait about 5 seconds before starting to press keys, and then press a few, then the output I get is the following:

```
Keypresses: 0     Time: 0 seconds
Keypresses: 0     Time: 1 seconds
Keypresses: 0     Time: 2 seconds
Keypresses: 0     Time: 3 seconds
Keypresses: 0     Time: 4 seconds
Keypresses: 0     Time: 5 seconds
Keypresses: 1     Time: 6 seconds
Keypresses: 1     Time: 6 seconds
Keypresses: 2     Time: 7 seconds
Keypresses: 2     Time: 7 seconds
Keypresses: 2     Time: 8 seconds
Keypresses: 3     Time: 9 seconds
Keypresses: 3     Time: 9 seconds
Keypresses: 4     Time: 10 seconds
Keypresses: 4     Time: 10 seconds
Keypresses: 4     Time: 11 seconds
Keypresses: 5     Time: 11 seconds
Keypresses: 5     Time: 11 seconds
Keypresses: 5     Time: 12 seconds
Keypresses: 6     Time: 12 seconds
Keypresses: 6     Time: 13 seconds
Keypresses: 6     Time: 14 seconds
Keypresses: 7     Time: 15 seconds
Keypresses: 7     Time: 15 seconds
Keypresses: 7     Time: 16 seconds
Keypresses: 7     Time: 17 seconds
```

In your original program, you are using `std::system("cls");` to clear the screen, instead of printing a new line every time. In my program, I am not clearing the screen, however, you can uncomment the line `std::system("cls");` and it should work. I have already put it in the correct place. Note, however, that using `std::system` [is not recommended](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/). See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen) from the official Microsoft documentation for better alternatives.